# Ant design Form custom controls cannot be displayed correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

[image]

Requirements: I want a control like the pictrue shows, checkBoxGroup to select fruit type, and every checkItem includes a InputNumber control to input count that the fruit needed.

I try to customize a form control named CheckGroup. According to the official document, I define two interfaces, value and onChange.

When I put CheckGroup in Form.Item, I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading'map'). When I print the value in CheckGroup , it also shows undefined, but when I put CheckGroup outside the Form.Item, it can be displayed normally , and the value can also be passed successfully.

So how can I solve it? I'm not clear where the problem is.

Thanks!

[Repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-river-y3wzw?file=/src/components/customn.tsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

props `value` is passed into `Form.Item` from the `Form` component  and replaces the value that you specified
To correctly transfer the value, you must specify the props `initialValues` to the `Form`

```
<Form
  layout="vertical"
  initialValues={{
    googds: groupData
  }}
>
  {/**...**/}
  <Form.Item
    name="googds"
    label="Goods"
    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please Input Sex" }]}
  >
    {/****************  use like this *********************/}
    <CheckGroup />
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```